# Google apps how to send data from html file to code.gs variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a problem with my google apps script. I have created a dropdown select element that gets values from json and Im trying to pass the selected value back to code.gs within a variable. How can i accomplish this?
The json data comes from the function "join". Im trying to get the "id" variable to be used in the api call.

Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="droplist">
      </select>
      <button type="button"  onclick="values()" >Hae</button>
      <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(people) {
            var select = document.getElementById("droplist");
            for( var a of people) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = a[0] + " " + a[1];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getPeople();
      }());
      function values() {
        var x = []
        x.push.document.getElementById("droplist").selectedIndex;
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
        Logger.log(x)

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's code.gs function where im trying to get the data:

```
function join(x) {

  var id = [];
  id.push(x)
  Logger.log(x)
  Logger.log(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want multiple values as you names the function `values`. Then to do so, you can get the selected values by using `selectElement.selectedOptions` and extracting the data from them. Then you can call the join function with `google.script.run` like you do with `getPeople`.

Here is a minimum code example:
`Code.gs`

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
}

function join(values) {
  Logger.log(values)
}
```

`Page.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function values() {
        // Get the values
        const selected = document.getElementById("droplist").selectedOptions
        const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value)

        // Call the Apps Script function
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(_ => console.log('success'))
          .withFailureHandler(error => console.error(error))
          .join(values)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="droplist" multiple>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button onclick="values()">Send values!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

### References

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API) (Google Apps Scripts reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i figured this out myself. I'll post the solution tomorrow to my original question